# Spring Data REST: slow page summary

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have a finder defined as a Spring Data repository derived from MongoRepository which searches for 3 different attributes in MongoDB. All three have a single index.

```
public Page<Content> findByIdInOrAuthorUserNameInOrTagsIdIn(
    @Param("ids") Collection ids,                                                          
    @Param("userNames") Collection userName,                                                          
    @Param("tagIds") Collection tagIds,                                                            
    @Param("pageable") Pageable pageable);
```

The problem is that one attributes has a result set of 2,5 mio entries:

```
"page": {
   "size": 20,
   "totalElements": 2531397,
   "totalPages": 126570,
   "number": 5
}
```

So the query for a page is quite fast (13ms) as seen in the mongo log file:

```
2017-04-10T12:50:27.562+0200 I COMMAND  [conn68] command content.content command: find { find: "content", filter: { $or: [ { $or: [ { _id: { $in: [ "..." ] } }, { author.userName: { $in: [ "...", "..." ] } } ] }, { tags._id: { $in: [ "..." ] } } ] }, skip: 100, limit: 20 } planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 }, IXSCAN { tags._id: 1 }, IXSCAN { author.userName: 1 } keysExamined:120 docsExamined:120 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:20 reslen:21185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 13ms
```

But it seems that the page summary which counts the result takes ~117s:

```
2017-04-10T12:52:24.172+0200 I COMMAND  [conn68] command content.content command: count { count: "content", query: { $or: [ { $or: [ { _id: { $in: [ "..." ] } }, { author.userName: { $in: [ "...", "..." ] } } ] }, { tags._id: { $in: [ "..." ] } } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 }, IXSCAN { tags._id: 1 }, IXSCAN { author.userName: 1 } keysExamined:2531466 docsExamined:2531397 numYields:21190 reslen:44 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 42382 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 21191 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 21191 } } } protocol:op_query 116592ms
```

Is there a way to switch off the page summary or speed up the counting some how?

Comment: Not sure if this works, but have you tried a Slice instead of a Page: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html

Comment: That was exactly what I was locking for :) Slice can also be combined with the Pageable parameter. Thanks

Comment: Made it an answer so, you can close it, and the system doesn't think this is still unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Slice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) instead of `Page`. It is very similar to `Page`, but doesn't need the total count of elements.